# Wayland Window Top Bar/Size Issues

Tags: wayland

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Hey there! I'm trying to switch to wayland from X and some issues have been emerging in the daily use of my machine. First, when opening up the qBittorrent, I cannot maximize it when double clicking on the top bar, and it doesn't comply with my Scaling Factor, and stays small, which is really bad. And mpv doesn't even have a top bar!

Expectation:
[image]

[image]

Cold hard Reality:
[image]

doesn't even use my font for the title bar[image]

doesn't even have a top bar

Does anybody know how to fix these errors?